# Proving $\lim_{n\to+\infty} n\int_{0}^{\alpha}x^{n}\phi(x)dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $\phi : [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann integrable function. How can we show that $\forall\alpha\in[0,1)$, we have :
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty} n\int_{0}^{\alpha}x^{n}\phi(x)dx=0
$$
I need to find an upper bound to be able to find the limit but the problem lies in finding an upper bound for $\phi(x)$. Any hint would be much appreciated, a full answer is not necessary, and thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE, what's $f(x)$ in your definition?

Comment: What is $f(x)$?  What is $\alpha$ in the upper limit of the integral?

Comment: I think OP meant $\phi(x)$?

Comment: thanks for letting me know, fixed!

Comment: $\alpha$ are all real numbers between $0$ and $1$

Comment: Doesn't the fact that $\phi$ is Riemann integrable mean that $\phi$ is bounded?  Or is $\phi$ allowed to be improperly Riemann integrable?

Comment: As a first step $\left|n\int_{0}^{\alpha}x^{n}\phi(x)\;\text{d}x\right|\leq n\int_{0}^{\alpha}x^{n}\left|\phi(x)\right|\;\text{d}x$

Comment: As @saulspatz mentioned, $\phi\in\mathcal{R}([0,1])$ and is thus bounded from above by its... I hope things are clear now

Comment: You must have meant to say $\alpha\in [0, 1)$, because the statement isn't true when $\alpha=1$.  Take $\phi(x)\equiv1$ to see this.

Comment: Noted, and what would that supremum be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Hint]** : Notice that $$\displaystyle\left|n\int_{0}^{\alpha}x^{n}\phi(x)\;\text{d}x\right|\leq n\int_{0}^{\alpha}x^{n}\left|\phi(x)\right|\;\text{d}x$$
Now define $\Omega_{x}:=\underset{x\in[0,\alpha]}{\sup}|\phi(x)|$, can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you, things are clear now. Thank you Saul as well.